# How to add a Gift Card type product to the cart via REST API?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento2.2, magento2.4

I can't work out the syntax for adding a Gift Card product to the cart using the POST `/rest/V1/carts/mine/items` REST API endpoint. What product options need setting?

I gather that it needs giftcard amount, giftcard message, sender and recipient name and email address but how do I actually format that into a request body?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind solved it. The value in the `giftcard_amount` field must be saved as an allowed amount against the giftcard. Some extra bits will need doing if it's a "custom amount" giftcard.

```
{
  "cartItem": {
    "product_option": {
      "extension_attributes": {
        "giftcard_item_option": 
          {
            "giftcard_amount": 50.0000,
            "giftcard_sender_name": "test",
            "giftcard_recipient_name": "test",
            "giftcard_sender_email": "test@test.com",
            "giftcard_recipient_email": "test@test.com",
            "giftcard_message": "magento is stupid"
          }
        
      }
    },
    "qty": 1,
    "quote_id": {{YOUR_QUOTE_ID_HERE}},
    "sku": {{YOUR_SKU_HERE}}
  }
}
```